# Web Service Error: Http request is disabled

Tags: .net, web-services, wcf

I am trying to run a Web Service, but I get this error: 
"
An exception of type 'System.ServiceModel.FaultException`1' occurred in mscorlib.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: Http request is disabled."

The web service calls a stored procedure in the background, but it doesn't even get there when this exception occurs.

Let me know what other information to add here. I am running the application on VS 2015 with .NET framework 4.7.

I am not sure even where to begin looking for this. Can anyone tell me where I need to check for the problem?

EDIT: Contents of web.config file in the project:

NOTE: I recently had to reformat my laptop and the project was working fine before then. I think it may have to do with how I set up IIS, maybe some settings are wrong? The property "HTTP Activation" is checked in "Turn Windows features On or Off". Check image:
[image: Windows Features]

```html
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="SampleEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://Models/Admin.Admin.csdl|res://Models/Admin.Admin.ssdl|res://Models/Admin.Admin.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=TServer;initial catalog=T_DB;persist security info=True;user id=user;multipleactiveresultsets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient"/>
   </connectionStrings>
  <!--
    For a description of web.config changes for .NET 4.5 see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=235367.

    The following attributes can be set on the <httpRuntime> tag.
      <system.Web>
        <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />
      </system.Web>
  -->
  <system.web>
 <httpRuntime maxUrlLength="2097151" maxQueryStringLength="2097151"/>
 <webServices>
      <protocols>
        <add name="HttpGet"/>
        <add name="HttpPost"/>
      </protocols>
    </webServices>
    <!-- 
  Visual Basic options:
  Set strict="true" to disallow all data type conversions 
  where data loss can occur. 
  Set explicit="true" to force declaration of all variables.
  -->
    <compilation debug="true" strict="false" explicit="true" targetFramework="4.5">
      <assemblies>      
        <remove assembly="SolverSDKNet20"/>
        <add assembly="System.Data.Entity, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e077"/>
      </assemblies>
    </compilation>
    <pages controlRenderingCompatibilityVersion="4.0" clientIDMode="AutoID">
      <namespaces>
        <clear/>
        <add namespace="System"/>
        <add namespace="System.Collections"/>
        <add namespace="System.Collections.Generic"/>
        <add namespace="System.Collections.Specialized"/>
        <add namespace="System.Configuration"/>
        <add namespace="System.Runtime.Serialization"/>
        <add namespace="System.Text"/>
        <add namespace="System.Text.RegularExpressions"/>
        <add namespace="System.Linq"/>
        <add namespace="System.Xml.Linq"/>
        <add namespace="System.ServiceModel.Web"/>
        <add namespace="System.Web"/>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Caching"/>
        <add namespace="System.Web.SessionState"/>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Security"/>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Profile"/>
        <add namespace="System.Web.UI"/>
        <add namespace="System.Web.UI.WebControls"/>
        <add namespace="System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts"/>
        <add namespace="System.Web.UI.HtmlControls"/>
      </namespaces>
    </pages>
    <!--
  The <authentication> section enables configuration 
  of the security authentication mode used by 
  ASP.NET to identify an incoming user. 
  -->
    <authentication mode="Windows"/>
    <!--
  The <customErrors> section enables configuration 
  of what to do if/when an unhandled error occurs 
  during the execution of a request. Specifically, 
  it enables developers to configure html error pages 
  to be displayed in place of a error stack trace.

  <customErrors mode="RemoteOnly" defaultRedirect="GenericErrorPage.htm">
   <error statusCode="403" redirect="NoAccess.htm" />
   <error statusCode="404" redirect="FileNotFound.htm" />
  </customErrors>
  -->
  </system.web>
  <!-- 
    The system.webServer section is required for running ASP.NET AJAX under Internet
    Information Services 7.0.  It is not necessary for previous version of IIS.
  -->
  <system.webServer>
    <security>
      <requestFiltering>
        <requestLimits maxUrl="4294967295" maxQueryString="4294967295"/>
      </requestFiltering>
    </security>
    <directoryBrowse enabled="true" showFlags="Date, Time, Size, Extension, LongDate"/>
  </system.webServer>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <services>
      <service behaviorConfiguration="FacadeWCF.SampleBehavior" name="FacadeWCF.Admin.clsSampleService">
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange"/>
        <endpoint binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="wsHttpBinding_SampleService" contract="FacadeWCF.Admin.ISampleContract">
          <identity>
            <dns value="localhost"/>
          </identity>
        </endpoint>
        <endpoint binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="SSLwsHttpBinding_SampleService" contract="FacadeWCF.Admin.ISampleContract"/>
        <endpoint address="basicHttp" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="basicHttpBinding_SampleService" contract="FacadeWCF.Admin.ISampleContract"/>
        <endpoint address="basicHttp" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="SSLbasicHttpBinding_SampleService" contract="FacadeWCF.Admin.ISampleContract"/>
      </service>
      <service behaviorConfiguration="FacadeWCF.SampleRESTServiceBehavior" name="FacadeWCF.Admin.clsSampleRESTService">
        <endpoint behaviorConfiguration="FacadeWCF.SampleRESTEndpointBehavior" binding="webHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="webHttpBinding_SampleRESTService" contract="FacadeWCF.Admin.ISampleRESTContract"/>
        <endpoint address="ssl" behaviorConfiguration="FacadeWCF.SampleRESTEndpointBehavior" binding="webHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="SSLwebHttpBinding_SampleRESTService" contract="FacadeWCF.Admin.ISampleRESTContract"/>
      </service>      
    </services>
    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="basicHttpBinding_SampleService" closeTimeout="00:30:00" openTimeout="00:30:00" receiveTimeout="00:30:00" sendTimeout="00:30:00" maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647">
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxArrayLength="2147483647"/>
        </binding>
        <binding name="SSLbasicHttpBinding_SampleService" closeTimeout="00:30:00" openTimeout="00:30:00" receiveTimeout="00:30:00" sendTimeout="00:30:00" maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647">
          <readerQuotas maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxArrayLength="2147483647"/>
          <security mode="Transport"/>
        </binding>
      </basicHttpBinding>
      <wsHttpBinding>
        <binding name="wsHttpBinding_SampleService" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" messageEncoding="Mtom">
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxArrayLength="2147483647"/>
          <security mode="None">
            <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None" realm=""/>
            <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default"/>
          </security>
        </binding>
        <binding name="SSLwsHttpBinding_SampleService" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" messageEncoding="Mtom">
          <readerQuotas maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxArrayLength="2147483647"/>
          <security mode="Transport">
            <transport clientCredentialType="None"/>
          </security>
        </binding>
      </wsHttpBinding>
      <webHttpBinding>        
        <binding name="webHttpBinding_SampleRESTService" maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647"/>
        <binding name="SSLwebHttpBinding_SampleRESTService" maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647">
          <security mode="Transport"/>
        </binding>
      </webHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <behaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="FacadeWCF.SampleRESTEndpointBehavior">
          <webHttp helpEnabled="true" defaultOutgoingResponseFormat="Json"/>
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="FacadeWCF.SampleBehavior">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true"/>
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
          <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="2147483647"/>
        </behavior>
        <behavior name="FacadeWCF.SampleRESTServiceBehavior">
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
          <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="2147483647"/>
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>   
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true">
      <serviceActivations>
        <add relativeAddress="SampleService.svc" service="FacadeWCF.Admin.clsSampleService"/>
        <add relativeAddress="SampleRESTService.svc" service="FacadeWCF.Admin.clsSampleRESTService"/>
  <add relativeAddress="SampleDataService.svc" service="FacadeWCF.Admin.clsSampleDataService" factory="System.Data.Services.DataServiceHostFactory, Microsoft.Data.Services, Version=5.6.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e45"/>
      </serviceActivations>
    </serviceHostingEnvironment>
  </system.serviceModel>
  
  <appSettings file="User.config"/>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Spatial" publicKeyToken="31BF3856AD364E45" culture="neutral"/>
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-5.6.0.0" newVersion="5.6.0.0"/>
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Data.Edm" publicKeyToken="31BF3856AD364E45" culture="neutral"/>
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-5.6.0.0" newVersion="5.6.0.0"/>
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Data.OData" publicKeyToken="31BF3856AD364E45" culture="neutral"/>
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-5.6.0.0" newVersion="5.6.0.0"/>
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Data.Services.Client" publicKeyToken="31BF3856AD364E45" culture="neutral"/>
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-5.6.0.0" newVersion="5.6.0.0"/>
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Post your config files code as well s service contract.

Comment: In your web config, you have defined <connectionStrings> <add name="SampleEntities"... but I can not see <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory ... installed in your solution and web config? Did you post the latest web.config?

Comment: @JailsonEvora: Not sure about that element. There haven't been any changes to that file recently and the project was working fine before I had  to reformat my laptop.

Comment: @Veda, do you checked the "HTTP Activation" for .net framework 4.5? So the problem could be in your IIS and confirm if you have the right configuration in Turn Windows features On or Off.

Comment: @JailsonEvora, Sorry my mistake, I just double-checked. I have .NET framework 4.7 and yes, I have HTTP Activation turned on for .NET 4.7 and also ".NET Framework 3.5 (includes 2.0 and 3.0)". All options under these two are checked. I have updated the question.

Comment: @Veda look for my contact in my profile and send me a private message, if you want or try to run your service in other machine, and you will see what happen.